# How to setup project using Alea GPU

Tags: c#, libraries, aleagpu

(Sorry if this is really obvious, I'm completely new to GPU programming.) I have installed all of the dependencies for Alea GPU and the samples are compiling and running as they should. However, I'm not sure how to setup a new console or windows forms project to include the Alea GPU libraries. If I just try to include the files as follows:

```
using Alea;
using Alea.Parallel;
```

I get the error:

> "The type or namespace name 'Alea' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

How am I supposed to include the Alea GPU libraries when creating a new project? (I'm using Visual Studio 2015)

Comment: Did you add a project reference to the assemblies for Alea?  That's required before the "using" statements can work

Comment: Are you adding the Alea libs via Nuget?  If you look at the list of references in your project, do you see the Alea dll in the list of references for the project?

Comment: @Taegost I was missing the project references to Alea. It's recognising the Alea libraries now. Thanks!

Comment: @SamuelBaileyCC I'm glad it was an easy fix!  I put that as an answer to this question, if you wouldn't mind marking it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the "using" statements will work, you need to add a reference to the project that points to the Alea library so Visual Studio knows where to look for them.